# What is an efficient way to farm 10,000 jute fiber for the achievement 'Skull and Jute'?

Tags: achievements, skull-and-bones

What optimal strategy can I apply to earn this achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can offer the following advice:

1. **Location**: From Saint-Anne, head north just past the very narrow river entrance to the group of about 3 islands. The biggest island has about 3 plants, but it's worth checking all. After this, head further north to the next group of islands with the small shipwreck. Lastly head to the tip of the landmass to the northeast where 2 more plants spawn.
   As soon as you reach the north or south end of this area, turn around and start over, the first plants you harvested will have likely respawned by now. Camping in a fixed spot seems to prevent the plants from respawning, but maybe I was not patient enough.
2. **Tools**: The highest level of sickle is the best. The higher the level, the bigger the green/purple section, which yield the most fiber per harvest. I only had access to the second best in my playthrough.
3. **Ship furniture**: There is a piece of furniture that gives you 1 extra yield of material if you manage to hit the purple section.
4. **Timing your clicks**: First of all turn off the setting to harvest automatically. This is much slower than manual harvesting. Secondly, aim to hit at least the green area in each second strike. The first strike, the yellow section give me 4 fiber, green 5 and purple 6.   Each second strike, the amounts for the green and purple sections increase to 8 or 9 fiber.
   Use the first strike to get the timing right, on the second harvest it is crucial to hit at least the green section. Purple will give you 1 extra, but hitting the yellow 'costs' around 4 jute, wich matters in the long run.
   A plant usually lets you harvest 6 times, 3 groups of 2 strikes after which the green/purple area moves, which can give you a theoretical maximum of 3x15 = 45 jute, each time you miss the green section on the second strike, you lose 10% of the potential amount.